# can we create two model or controller for same collection in sails js

Tags: sails.js, sails-mongo

I am new to sails js. I am using mongodb database. I have `users` collection. I have created api using `sails generate api users` it creates `Users.js` and `UsersController.js` files. I want to know that can we create another controller or model for the same collection?

I have created `User_dummy.js` and `User_dummyController.js` using same command given above. And copied the content of the file `Users.js` into `User_dummy.js` and `UsersController.js` file into `User_dummyController.js`. But it doesn't work.

Its giving me following error :

```
Trying to associate a collection attribute to a model that doesn't have a Foreign Key.
```

I want to make two copies of both model and controller for `users` collection. Is there any solution or is there any way to create two controller or model.

Comment: I want to know that is it compulsory that the model's name is same as the collection's name? For example: our mongodb contains `users` collection and we have to create model as `User.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `tableName` model setting ([see documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?tablename)) to have a shared collection for two or more models.

Users.js/User_dummy.js:

```
module.exports = {

  tableName: 'users',

  attributes: {

  }
};
```